# Programmatically switching views using UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

I can't switch to another view controller using UITableView. My code is like below.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let dashViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("menuView") as DashViewController
        self.presentViewController(dashViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

    }
```

[image]

I click one of my cells, and it just does nothing.

Comment: Have you stepped through it? Is your didSelect... method getting called?

Comment: if you print something inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath do you get any output when you click?

Comment: wait, i try first. wait.

Comment: I already print out something , no output.

NSLog("Clicked!!")

Comment: did u set the delegate `self.tableView.delegate = self` ?

Comment: I got Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDelegate'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found the answer, I forgot to put `UITableViewDelegate`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

}
```

And assign tableview with view controller

[image]